# how to display all days in any month in a datagridview in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I am still new in wpf development. I have a datagrid with 7 columns, days of the week(sunday to saturday). I want to display the days of any month depending on the user's selection on the grid. May someone please help me with this? thank you. At the moment, I have a switch case for all the months in a year and I can get the days in the month, I just need to know how to add the result to the datagrid and for the days to fall on the right day.

this is what I have;

```
 switch (cTvDaySelected)
            {

                case "January":
                    var dates = new List<string>();
                    for (var date = new DateTime(d1.Year, d1.Month, 1); date.Month == d1.Month; date = date.AddDays(1))
                    {
                        dates.Add(date.ToLongDateString().Substring(0,2));
                        //for (int i = 0; i < dates.Count; i++)
                        //{
                        //    dm.sun = date.ToLongTimeString().Substring(0,2);
                        //}
                    }

                    dm.sun = dates.FirstOrDefault();
                    MonthModel.Add(dm);
                    month_record.ItemsSource = MonthModel;
                    break;
            }
```

Comment: There's a dayofweek property on Datetime. Build a datetime with just the date in it for each day. Then you can use dayofweek on each of them. Maybe that's only obvious when you know how.  But it seems kind of obvious. A more interesting aspect to what you're doing is how you translate data associated with a day into that datagrid and back to however you're going to persist it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DateTime.DaysInMonth` function will help you in your situation. Here is similar logic which can help you to get your desire output.

```
int Year = 2019;
int Month = 2;

int TotalDaysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(Year, Month);
for (int i = 1; i <= TotalDaysInMonth; i++)
{
    DateTime dt = new DateTime(Year, Month, i);
    // Insert it into your Model...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. The above method looks like it gets all the days in the month but how do I know which day is monday, tuesday and so on?

Comment: You can use `DayOfWeek` Property of `DateTime` class. Here you can use `dt.DayOfWeek`

Comment: Hi, I already did that. I am now facing one problem, how to show all the days in the month. The binding in my datagrid columns is the days of the week in my model. those feilds in the model get replaced and only the last days get shown on the datagrid

Comment: Can you please post your binding logic.

Comment: <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=sun}" IsReadOnly="True" x:Name="colMSun" Header="Sunday" Width="Auto"/>

Comment: I have that for the 7 days of the week

Comment: your model should contains 7 `List<string>` which can hold your all X days of particular month.

Comment: it does. that is what my datagrid is bind to

Comment: Hi sorry to be a bother but I created the list but nothing shows on the grid